# Django force makemigrations to use tabs instead of spaces

Tags: django, python-2.7, manage.py

When I run python manage.py makemigrations myapp, it generates a migration file 0001_initial.py that is indented using 4 spaces.

I want tabs. Is there any way I can set it? (No opinions on 4 spaces vs tabs please.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a configurable setting to switch from spaces to tabs. If you really want to do this, you would have to override the [`OperationWriter.feed`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.4/django/db/migrations/writer.py#L101) method, which is hardcoded to use spaces.

```
def feed(self, line):
    self.buff.append(' ' * (self.indentation * 4) + line)
```

Comment: Well that was worth a shot I guess :|. Great find too! Thanks!